# add duplicate value in multi dimensional array in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a 2d array in classic asp like 

1-5
1-3
2-5

I need this array output in following format
1-8
2-5

please help me

Comment: Are you looking just to get a sum of all the values in the 1st dimension?

Comment: yes, I'm looking just to get a sum of all the values in the 1st dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dictionary to sum up the col2 values grouped by the col1 values. As in:

```
  ReDim aIn(2, 1)
  aIn(0, 0) = 1 : aIn(0, 1) = 5
  aIn(1, 0) = 1 : aIn(1, 1) = 3
  aIn(2, 0) = 2 : aIn(2, 1) = 5
  Dim dicX : Set dicX = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i
  For i = LBound(aIn, 1) To UBound(aIn, 1)
      dicX(aIn(i, 0)) = dicX(aIn(i, 0)) + aIn(i, 1)
  Next
  ReDim aOut(dicX.Count - 1, 1)
  For i = LBound(aOut, 1) To UBound(aOut, 1)
      aOut(i, 0) = dicX.Keys()(i)
      aOut(i, 1) = dicX(aOut(i, 0))
  Next
  For i = LBound(aOut, 1) To UBound(aOut, 1)
      WScript.Echo aOut(i, 0), aOut(i, 1)
  Next
```

output:

```
======
1 8
2 5
======
```

Comment: Thanks. It's useful for me